# Jenkins : how to use Credentials Binding Plugin to Execute Windows Batch Command

Tags: git, shell, batch-file, jenkins, execute

Running "set" in either command prompt or Jenkins "Execute Windows Batch Command", I see that I am not executing the command under a specific name.

Looking at [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) I cannot figure out how to add credentials to this specific "Execute Windows Batch Command". All images I found points to CloudBees Jenkins version, I use plain Jenkins.

How do I use Credentials Binding Plugin to Execute Windows Batch Command?

Comment: Could you run your Jenkins service as a user, instead of the system account?

Comment: Thanks VonC, I just ran it under my own account and that worked. The complication here is that I would need to create this user under AD, bitbucket, and assign it to the different groups that we use under the (many) bitbucket projects. It would have been ideal to apply the credentials to the specific execute command, do you think this is possible or is only option to run as a user? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always run the Windows Jenkins service as a specific technical user account (always the same)

That account has nothing to do with the actual account used to authenticate on the remote server (BitBucket or GitLab or GitHub)

It is just there to have a clear defined `%USERPROFILE%` (used as `$HOME` by Git by default) in which I can set authentication parameters.

I use for that ssh keys (instead of https urls), including the right key to authentication with the right remote account.

Answer (score 1):

Select the "use secret text(s) or file(s) and then add a binding.  See screenshot :

[image]